# jquery addClass() not working with event.target

Tags: jquery, events, target, addclass

Please help.

Why is the jquery `addClass()` not working with `event.target`?
I have made a code and it supposed to add class on the target when clicked, but it does not work, and it says,`e.target.addClass` is not a function.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lq9G4/

CODE:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Class Test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .big {
            font-size: 5em;
        }
        .small {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <p>This is the text</p>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("p").click(function(e) {  
                      $("a").removeClass("big").addClass("small");
                      $("this").addClass("big"); //This doesn't work
                      e.target.addClass("big"); //nor this one                
                    });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Basically e.target will be a `javascript` object, you have to convert it into a `Jquery` object before utilizing its functions like `.addClass()`

Try,

```
$(e.target).addClass("big");
```

and at the same time, `$("this").addClass("big");` this code will not work since you are passing `this` as a string. `this` also a javascript object, you need to convert that too as a jquery object like `$(this)`

Comment: @user3540736 i had given some explanations regarding that in my answer.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You have **two** problem:

```
$(this).addClass("big"); //Unquote to "this"
$(e.target).addClass("big"); // select e.target with $() wrapper.
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line

```
$("this").addClass("big"); //This doesn't work
```

to

```
$(this).addClass("big"); //This will work work
```

And further if you need it with the `event` itself then you can use

```
$(e.target).addClass('big');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `.addClass()` is a jQuery method, you need a jQuery object, so convert `e.target` to jQuery object by wrapping it inside `$`:

```
$(e.target).addClass("big");
```

Beside that, the other solution is to use `$(this)`. you don't need to wrap `this` inside `" "`:

```
$(this).addClass("big");
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq9G4/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $(e.target).addClass('big');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq9G4/5/)**

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("p").click(function(e) {
                  $("a").removeClass("big").addClass("small");
                  $(this).addClass("big"); //This doesn't work               
                });
    });

</script>
```

"this"=>this

Answer (score 2):

```
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("loading_arrow");
```

> you can use above line to add loading_arrow class using js mouse event.