# Converting pure JS to jquery for array[i].className?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pure JS function in which i have tried to convert majority to jquery. How do I set the entire function to a proper `jquery syntax`?

```
 function openResources(e, resourceName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tabs;
    tabcontent = $(".resources__all-tabs-container");

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {;
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }

    tabs = $(".resources__tabs");

    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace(" 
 resources__all-tabs", "");
    }

    document.getElementById(resourceName).style.display= "block";
    //$(`"`+ resourceName + `"`)[0].style.display ="block";
    e.currentTarget.className += " resources__all-tabs";

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget you can chain functions in jQuery.

```js
function openResources(e, resourceName) {
  $(".resources__all-tabs-container").hide();
  $(".resources__tabs").removeClass('resources__all-tabs');
  $('#' + resourceName).show();
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass('resources__all-tabs');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
tabcontent = $(".resources__all-tabs-container");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {;
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Would be:

```
$(".resources__all-tabs-container").hide();
```

see here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

This:

```
tabs = $(".resources__tabs");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabs[i].className = tabs[i].className.replace("resources__all-tabs", "");
}
```

Should be replaced with:

```
$(".resources__tabs").removeClass("resources__all-tabs")
```

See here: https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/

This:

```
document.getElementById(resourceName).style.display= "block";
```

Has to be replaced with:

```
$("#" + resourceName).show();
```

See here: http://api.jquery.com/show/

This:

```
e.currentTarget.className += " resources__all-tabs";
```

Should be:

```
$(e.currentTarget).addClass("resources__all-tabs");
```

See here: [jquery addClass() not working with event.target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211129/jquery-addclass-not-working-with-event-target)

Answer (score 0):

```
function openResources(e, resourceName) {
  $(".resources__all-tabs-container").hide();
  $(".resources__tabs").removeClass("resources__all-tabs");
  $("#" + resourceName).show();
  $(e.currentTarget).addClass("resources__all-tabs");
}
```

Should be the equivalent code.

Comment: `this` is not necessarily what OP wants. Plus he wants to show `#resourceName`, not hide it.

Comment: @Zenoo oh yea missed that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
function openResources(e, resourceName) {
    var tabcontent = $(".resources__all-tabs-container"), 
        tabs = $(".resources__tabs");

    // hide all tabs and show the one that matches `resourceName`
    tabcontent.hide().filter('#' + resourceName).show();

    // set current tab as selected
    $(e.target).addClass('resources__all-tabs')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
function openResources(e, resourceName) {
      $('.resources__all-tabs-container').each(function() {
          $(this).hide();
      })

      $('.resources__tabs').each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('.resources__tabs');
      })

      $('#'+resourceName).show();
      $(e.target).addClass('resources__all-tabs');
   }
```

Comment: No need for each - see the other answers